# Simple number counter - PIC16F877A microcontroller problem

Tags: microcontroller, counter, mplab

[image]I am trying to make a simple counter using pic16f877a. I want to count each time a push button is pressed, that is taking one press as one count, **regardless of how long the button is pressed**.

The software I am using are MPLAB X IDE and XC8 compiler. I use Pickit 3.5.  I use an indicator LED to see whether the code is working.

The thing is, I have barely achieved what I needed, but the code seems unstable. It works sometimes but not in others. For example, let say the code worked now and LED blinked correctly when one of two connected buttons pushed. Then if I "make" and "download" the program again without any edits to the code in MPLAB X IDE, the LED won't blink. While writing this I tested several times just by making and downloading using MPLAB IDE, without changing anything hardware or code, and then it worked. The only thing that was changed in those situations was TIME. I suspect this has something to do with resetting of the PIC although I have no idea. **Never worked on 2 consecutive "make and download"s.**

**Code:**

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pic16f877a.h>
// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS    
#pragma config WDTE = OFF    
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF   
#pragma config BOREN = OFF   
#pragma config LVP = OFF    
#pragma config CPD = OFF  
#pragma config WRT = OFF        
#pragma config CP = OFF

void main(void) {
    TRISB=0;//LED connected to RB0
    TRISD=1;//two push buttons connected to RD0(buttonRight) and RD1(buttonLeft)

    while(1)
    {
        if (PORTDbits.RD0==0)//if buttonRight is pressed,
        {
            __delay_ms(5);//debouncing.
            if (PORTDbits.RD0==0)//if buttonRight is still pressed,
            {
                PORTBbits.RB0=1;
                __delay_ms(500);
                PORTBbits.RB0=0;
                __delay_ms(500);

                /*to take as one press no matter for how long it is pressed.*/
                while(PORTDbits.RD0==0);
            }
        }

        else if (PORTDbits.RD1==0)//if buttonLeft is pressed,
        {
            __delay_ms(5);//debouncing.
            if (PORTDbits.RD1==0)//if buttonLeft is still pressed,
            {
                PORTBbits.RB0=1;
                __delay_ms(100);
                PORTBbits.RB0=0;
                __delay_ms(100);

                /*to take as one press no matter for how long it is pressed.*/
                while(PORTDbits.RD1==0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the rest of the circuit look like? Power supply, connections to PIC etc...

Comment: Do you have decoupling caps near your uC?

Comment: @Tyler not near uC, but near the pickit connection Vdd and Vss are connected by a capacitor on breadboard.

Comment: Are you talking about C3 (on your schematic)?

Comment: @stackUsr - stop messing about and show us the full schematic. If you knew which bits were relevant and which weren't you wouldn't be asking this question here.

Comment: @brhans i added a new full schematic. i am a beginner so think i did it right.

Comment: You really have your pushbuttons connected to RB7/PGD? That'll never work.

Comment: @brhans it was a terrible mistake. fixed it.

Comment: `TRISB=0;` sets the whole of portB (all 8 pins) as outputs. `TRISD=1;` sets RD0 as an input, and the rest of portD as outputs. Is this what you intended?

Comment: Well you have a button on RD1 that you'll never be able to read if RD1 is an output. And you're only using RB0 for your LED so there's no real reason to set the rest of portB as outputs.

Comment: @brhans In my understanding, i thought TRISB=0; sets every B pin as output, and TRISD=1 sets ALL D pins as inputs. If not please tell me how to get this working. (I did so since RD0 and RD1 are the pins to which buttons connected. )

Comment: @brhans You are RIGHT!! adding "TRISD0=1; and TRISD1=1" makes the code work everytime! although i have no idea what was the reason it worked. I thought TRISD=1 was the way to go. Why is that? Please post as answer if you will.

Answer (score 1):

Port D0 and Port D1 should be an input.
If you write:

```
TRISD = 1;
```

you only make PortD.1 an input.

Maybe ist clearer if you think in binary:

```
TRISD = 1:
```

is simular to:

```
TRISD = 0b00000001;
```

which writes 1 only to Port D.0 and put all other Pin of D to 0. So write:

```
TRISD = 0b00000011;
```